# jquery.validate.js Not Working?

Tags: jquery, validation

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong here:
http://adam-sites-for-clients.info/set-up/

I'm using this:
http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation

and my code is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#myForm").validate();
</script>
```

Ideas???

Comment: Did you setup validation options ?

Comment: You need to tell the plug how and what to validate. Check out the tab "view source" at http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation#Example

Comment: What do you mean by validation options?
the documentation says it has a default built in

Answer (score 1):

Remove your form and paste this in:

```
<form class="optin" method="post" action="submit.php" id="myForm">
  <label for="name" class="label"><img src="images/label1.png" alt="" /></label>
  <input type="text" name="name" class="textbox required" id="name" />
  <label for="phone" class="label move"><img src="images/label2.png" alt="" /></label>
  <input type="text" name="phone" class="textbox required" id="phone" />
  <label for="email" class="label move"><img src="images/label3.png" alt="" /></label>
  <input type="text" name="email" class="textbox required email" id="email" />
  <input type="submit" class="submit" name="submit" value="" />
  <input id="topic" type="hidden" name="topic" value="homepage">
</form>
```

...then read the documentation, then go from there.

Notice the classes I added to the `<input>` elements?

Comment: thanks bro!
I actually read the documentation. Guess I missed that :)